# Why HTML5 form doesn't show me google search results?

Tags: html, google-search

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search?q=" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
</form>
```

Whenever I type something in the `input` and press enter it goes to `https://www.google.com/webhp?search=my+search`. Why doesn't it goes through google and show me results?

Comment: Hope this maybe help you out https://technosmarter.com/php/how-to-google-search-input-box-in-website

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://www.howto-connect.com/google-webhp/):

> Google.com/webhp (Google co webhp) is type of redirect virus which affects the settings of the browser and redirects us to other websites. If you want to search something in Google search it takes us to some harmful pages rather than the normal one.

And for google search try this one:

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var search = form.querySelector("input[type=search]");
  search.value = search.value;
  form.submit();
});
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search"  type="GET">
  <label>
     Search Google: 
     <input type="search" name="q">
   </label>

  <input type="submit" value="Go">

</form>
```

Comment: @Plaban Note that the snippet work well in my computer. But it seems to have problem with Stack snippet